# SILVERLIGHT sending file to server

Tags: silverlight, webclient

I am using PhotoChooserTask to select image from windows phone and then I want to send this `file/image` to the server.

`WebClient` has method `UploadFile` but `WebClient` in `Silverlight` has not this method.
I was trying to use few examples which I found on this forum but it is not working. Can anyone help me do this from the begining? I really dont understand how `Silverlight` is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webclient class for uploading file as

```
private void UploadFile()
        {
            FileStream _data; // The file stream to be read
            string uploadUri;

            byte[] fileContent = new byte[_data.Length]; 
            int bytesRead = _data.Read(fileContent, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.OpenWriteCompleted += new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenWriteCompleted);
            Uri u = new Uri(uploadUri);
            wc.OpenWriteAsync(u, null, new object[] { fileContent, bytesRead }); 
        }

        void wc_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
              // Upload completed without error
            }
        }
```

On Server side you can handle like

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.InputStream.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("No file input");
        if (context.Request.QueryString["fileName"] == null)
            throw new Exception("Parameter fileName not set!");

        string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"];
        string filePath = @HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/" + fileName;
        bool appendToFile = context.Request.QueryString["append"] != null && context.Request.QueryString["append"] == "1";

        FileMode fileMode;
        if (!appendToFile)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                File.Delete(filePath);
            fileMode = FileMode.Create;
        }
        else
        {
            fileMode = FileMode.Append;
        }
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, fileMode))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I don't understand your `Server side code`. Server which will receive data shuold have that code? So there is a little problem: my serwer is with php not c#.

Comment: I have not worked with PHP. but in c# 'Server Side code' means whenever you are calling any page like Home.aspx from client side,On server side on page load we can handle above 'Server side code.'

Comment: I used your code, only change one line `FileStream _data = (FileStream)e.ChosenPhoto; ` where e.ChoosenPhoto is result of PhotoChooserTask. Server didnt get any request from this code.

Comment: Open the Filestream as `FileStream _data = new FileStream ("path",FileMode.Open);`

Comment: Ok, i have `FileStream _data = new FileStream(e.OriginalFileName, FileMode.Open);` where e.OriginalFileName is `\\Applications\\Data\\52BD42C5-9796-450A-B62B-028508CF26E2\\Data\\PlatformData\\PhotoChooser-b70f8d7f-3f81-4cc5-8a0e-764892d379ab.jpg` and this code throws exception `{"Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode)"}`

Comment: FileStream has no permition to open that file. I found, that i must copy that file to local storage. I found a code to do this, from local storage this code ` FileStream _data = store.OpenFile("imagetmp.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` doesnt throw exception but still server didnt get request.